# How to structure multiform steps with static header and menu bar

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, registration

I am making an app, where the user registration goes over 4 pages. I have a top bar with logo, and a menu bar in the bottom made from images, which will both be shown to the user on all 4 pages. Before starting to make 4 different view controllers and copying the top bar elements and my bottom menu, I wonder if there is some better way to do this. Like having one view controller and then switching in and out some views which holds the elements that need to be in the mid-screen (mainly to avoid copying the header a footer elements, and also to avoid my storyboard getting very messy with all the VCs)? Any advice on how to structure the user registration will be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Why not use a navigation controller with its tool bar visible? This does leave you with 4 controllers in the storyboard, but I wouldn't call that messy (you can put them in a separate storyboard from the rest of your app if you want).

Comment: Well this doesn't provide any help on how to deal with the static header and bottom. Afaik a navigation bar is placed in the top, but anyway Im customizing an app for someone. But I think I was clear enough in my post, with that I wonder if I should "load" mid-center elements into a fixed background somehow

Comment: You can do what I think you want by using a custom container controller with those fixed elements at the top and bottom, and a view in the center which you switch out. You can do this in the storyboard by adding those top and bottom elements to a controller, and a container view to the middle. That will give you a view controller embedded in the container view. You can switch that out in code using the custom container api documented in the UIViewController class reference.

Comment: Since I still have multiple VCs, I have decided to make an .xib for both the header and the footer. I will in the relevant VC then just make 4 views and use the hidden property to switch them around, kinda like android view flipper. If anybody has a better idea, please shoot, or Ill think this would be the answer and we can call the case closed.